# Open word document from ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net

I use the following code snippet to open a local docx file and it runs fine when I press Ctrl+F5 in Visual Studio. I just click the button and the Word2007 on my machine is opened and the docx is displayed there. But after I publish the application to the production server, it didn't work. After I click the same button, nothing happened. Could someone tell me why?

What I want is to open a local stored docx in client side's Word 2007 from asp.net application. I don't want to use office COM object.

My code:

```
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"winword.exe",@"/test.docx");
    Process.Start(psi);
```

Many thanks.

Comment: why do you need to open winword.exe? read file content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is attempting to open Word on the server and not on the client. The only reason it works in development is the the client and server are on the same machine.

You cannot open Word on the client due to browser security restrictions. However if you provide a link to the file, the user will be able to download and open the file if they have Word installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open a local stored document, on the client's machine, you should create a link to the document (using the path on the client's harddisk). The browser will ask the user for permission to open it, but this should work.

The reason your code worked, was because the server and the client are the same machine when debugging. The development server even runs using your profile.

In production the server can be on the other side of the world. The C# code you show in your snippet is executed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file exists in the same location.

ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo()
is working on server and it is trying to pick the file from server location and it can never run client side file.

Comment: It's not only trying to pick the file from the server, it's starting Word *on the server*.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is let them download the file.  If they don't have office, or don't have the right compatability pack, they won't be able to open it.