# Word document viewer in asp web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, com, activex

I've to create one asp web application using C# to show word document(docx) in the form(browser window). Is there any active control or COM components are available for that means help to achieve it
 please help me ...

Comment: There is a good solution here -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929285/xslt-or-library-to-convert-open-xml-to-rtf-in-net

it doesn't rely on using activex.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182654/open-word-document-from-asp-net-application

Comment: Is der any free plugin to accomplish that task. view user word document through these plugin